# Python multiprocessing - Reaching 100 % of all cores

Tags: python, ubuntu, multiprocessing

I am running this code on my quad-core computer with Ubuntu:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

tmp = [pool.apply_async(get_solution, args)
       for args in arguments]  # len(arguments) == 4

solutions = tuple(map(methodcaller('get'), tmp))
```

`get_solution` is a function which runs only once for a few seconds. When I run this code, I get the following usage graph in htop:

[image]

The presented code is a part of [this repository](https://github.com/sglumac/pyislands).

Can you please help me? Is there a way to force python to use 100 % of all cores?

Comment: Does increasing number of processes from 4->8 help? Almost looks like you are using half of your CPUs, making me wonder if one core is actually hyperthreaded to two (though it should be visible in the screenshot)

Comment: Load average (and I think % usage) is not instantaneous; the smallest sample window shown is over 1 minute.  If you are running this function 4 times on 4 cores and it takes only a few seconds to run, it's not going to drive up your load average very much.  The only way to "force" Python to use all your cores is to throw more parallel work at the CPU.  Also, if each batch only takes a few seconds to run, you might end up bottlenecked on the master process.  Maybe you can figure out how to batch the work in to larger chunks so each worker can run fully autonomously for a minute or 2.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I tried this and it only made thing slower, Silas's comment improved things.

Comment: @SilasRay Thank you, you helped alot (I was affraid all my work with multiprocessing was in vain). Each process was solving a travelling salesman problem and appears the problem presented above was to simple. I tried solving a bigger problem (with smaller running time) and I got almost 100%. Could you please make this an official answer so that I can accept it?